# Fancybox won't close when click spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want the fancybox to close when either of the spans are clicked, currently it seems to be reopening the window after they are clicked and clicking anywhere else closes it like it should.

```
<div class="fancybox" style="display: none;">
    <span class="ChooseEnglish">English</span>
    <span class="ChooseCymraeg">Cymraeg</span>
</div>    

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick: true
});
$( ".fancybox" ).trigger( "click" );

$( ".ChooseEnglish" ).click(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
$( ".ChooseCymraeg" ).click(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8NDm/

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the selector `.fancybox` is bound to fancybox **but** it's also the *content* of fancybox. In other words, that selector is both the **trigger** and the **target** of fancybox.

Of course, any `click` on the selector and/or its contents (your `<span>`) will trigger fancybox over an over again.

You need another selector to fire fancybox (that can be hidden if you prefer so) like :

```
<a href="#fancybox" class="fancybox" style="display: none;"><a>
```

Then change the `div` selector from *class* to *ID* so it can be targeted by the link like :

```
<div id="fancybox" style="display: none;">
    <span class="ChooseEnglish">English</span>
    <span class="ChooseCymraeg">Cymraeg</span>
</div>
```

and finally the simplified script :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick: true
}).trigger("click"); // you can chain fancybox and trigger methods

$(".ChooseEnglish, .ChooseCymraeg").click(function () {
    $.fancybox.close();
}); // bind the same click event to both selectors at once
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Stf8/)</kbd>

---

**NOTE**: if you want to prevent the visitor from closing fancybox **without** choosing any of your (`<span>`) options, then you can add `modal:true` instead like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // force to close clicking on any span only
    modal: true
}).trigger("click");
```

See forked <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Stf8/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The click event is bubbling from the span to the div, so the fancybox gets reopened. You can use `.stopPropagation` to prevent bubbling:

```
$( ".ChooseEnglish" ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.fancybox.close();
});
$( ".ChooseCymraeg" ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```